# Postfix keeps answering "User unknown in local recipient table"

Tags: ubuntu, postfix

I am trying to set up postfix (on ubuntu 18.04) to accept incoming email locally, with no relaying involved.
I've made it work fine for users that actually exist in the system, but I want it to handle arbitrary recipients as long as the domain is mine. Basically, I want to specify the valid recipients without creating them as unix users.

I have set `local_recipient_maps=`

I have tried `luser_relay=existing_user`

I have tried `virtual_alias_maps=pcre:/etc/mailist/recipients`, a file containing `/.*/ existing_user`, which is readable by anyone.

(existing_user always is a real user that I have succesfully sent mail to)

I even added an entry to /etc/aliases, which is configured as alias_maps, and ran `newaliases`, without success.

And of course I have reloaded and restarted postfix after each change, so that's not the problem.

Creating a new user in the system works fine, I can immediately send mail to that user.

I have no clue. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

OK, it was too late in the evening for me... reading error logs helps. I kept looking in mail.log and forgot checking mail.err .

I still wonder why `luser_relay` did not work as expected, but it was not the way I wantoed to go anyway.

`/etc/aliases.db` somehow gives a "permission denied", that's why changing it did not help. But I won't investigate this, because it also is not my favored solution.

The reason my `virtual_alias_maps=pcre:/etc/mailist/recipients` didn't work was simply that I did not have `postfix-pcre` installed.